# Azure AD SAML2 response: System.Security.Cryptography not supporting http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256

Tags: saml-2.0, azure-active-directory, kentor-authservices

everyone. I have a mystery. It may be obvious to someone, hence this.

About 10 days ago, my Service Provider app started to throw a curious error after working flawlessly for several weeks. I have a service provider running both locally and on Azure. The app uses KentorAuthServices to handle the messy XML and crypto bits. It was running smoothly and then, suddenly, it began to throw the error, "Could not create hash algorithm object." I enabled framework debugging and traced it to the very location indicated in the last line of this extract of the stack trace:

```
[CryptographicException: Could not create hash algorithm object.]
   System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference.CalculateHashValue(XmlDocument document, CanonicalXmlNodeList refList) +160912
   System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckDigestedReferences() +154
   System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignature(AsymmetricAlgorithm key) +73
```

Indeed, it cannot create the hash algorithm object because the algorithm represented by this URI

http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256

now purports to be unsupported, despite having a custom handler for it built into KentoAuthServices-and which worked as expected until this sudden turn of events. Just as a sanity check, I pointed the SP app at Kentor's own stub IdP and the app behaves as expected. As well, I validated the SAML response, which I will reproduce below, against OneLogin's SAML validation utility, which also reports that the response is valid but that the algorithm is unsupported.

Things I do know:

- The Azure AD cert is current, complete, and accessible in the Trusted
  Root cert store of LocalMachine, and created after the October 10
  policy change for rollovers (which should be irrelevant here anyway).
- The SP is not signing the request with any kind of funky, self-signed
  cert; nor did it ever.
- Both locally and on Azure, the app is pegged to
  an SSL port.
- The configuration of the app--EntityId, Issuer, metadata
  location and loading, binding, request signing behavior; and so
  on--has remained unchanged--except for my testing, which added a swappable IdP reference pointed to the stub provider.
- Azure AD successfully processes the request and
  issues a response, which is otherwise valid; however,
  System.Security.Cryptography cannot create the hash for the
  signature.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, except for the fact that the app was unchanged from one day to the next; hence, I'm obliged to ask if anything in the world has changed to explain why rsa-sha256 is coming up dead. Here's the redacted SAML request and response for your perusal. Most identifying info is removed, but you already know it's from Azure AD so the cert is present and you can validate it for your edification. Thanks, and have a great day.

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest
xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
ID="id1cf99748a239485692824ff1b950b5f9"
Version="2.0"
IssueInstant="2016-11-29T16:44:34Z"
Destination="https://login.windows.net:443/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/saml2"
AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/AuthServices/Acs">
<saml2:Issuer>https://xxxxx.xxx/federation</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>

<samlp:Response 
    ID="_xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" 
    Version="2.0" 
    IssueInstant="2016-11-29T16:44:36.521Z" 
    Destination="https://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/AuthServices/Acs" 
    InResponseTo="id1cf99748a239485692824ff1b950b5f9" 
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer 
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/
    </Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode 
            Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </samlp:Status>
    <Assertion 
        ID="_xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" 
        IssueInstant="2016-11-29T16:44:36.505Z" 
        Version="2.0" 
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <Issuer>https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/</Issuer>
        <ds:Signature 
            xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod 
                    Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <ds:SignatureMethod 
                    Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <ds:Reference 
                    URI="#_2a5aa895-bcf1-4f98-87d6-187e7d75338c">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform 
                            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                        <ds:Transform 
                            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod 
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>
                        HE62WvhO505xxxxxxxxnopQTPfL6LybGYySKUKfBxtY=
                    </ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>E8bvvT1iw148RaVOtlPWWMhPMq121arxJ2lwRd3Boi5Xe3Lw+sc9TgCWsmFa4tcIq0idmYTkYVio4cBDNnzIcMqy28JeeiF53nriO3eyxRQiPeJhyy6JUFnbhWEa6DcYvIbD14izrvdQGuGzULeL8K2cc32xDnCjYZXAWvY4V+iaEJhXqc50bfplUXwTcgo2YzPckmh/+iad0jVFBBj1S7bMDp9+hOvUHgrwU/FIm8H7Y/g6rZZ2mlkEsdRP0WRQfCgI/IHLf1IqUdaGE9hZpqcecmtAiKytWIe/0z/8zzUC3Xp2f+L2XEXMH3Y7iNOyKr38X3FQ/
                OChWEdYLIj3rw==
            </ds:SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo 
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <X509Data>
                    <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <Subject>
            <NameID 
                Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@Xxxxxxxxxxx.com
            </NameID>
            <SubjectConfirmation 
                Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <SubjectConfirmationData 
                    InResponseTo="id1cf99748a239485692824ff1b950b5f9" 
                    NotOnOrAfter="2016-11-29T16:49:36.505Z" 
                    Recipient="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/AuthServices/Acs"/>
            </SubjectConfirmation>
        </Subject>
        <Conditions 
            NotBefore="2016-11-29T16:39:36.505Z" 
            NotOnOrAfter="2016-11-29T17:39:36.505Z">
            <AudienceRestriction>
                <Audience>https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/federation</Audience>
            </AudienceRestriction>
        </Conditions>
        <AttributeStatement>
            <Attribute 
                Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid">
                <AttributeValue>ccbf68cb-7932-44bd-b015-cb686e0a4441</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute 
                Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier">
                <AttributeValue>94d0114a-c4b8-4568-bf63-4b597aa65eda</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute 
                Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname">
                <AttributeValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute 
                Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider">
                <AttributeValue>live.com</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute 
                Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname">
                <AttributeValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute 
                Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname">
                <AttributeValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute 
                Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
                <AttributeValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute 
                Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
                <AttributeValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeStatement>
        <AuthnStatement 
            AuthnInstant="2016-11-27T02:37:17.000Z" 
            SessionIndex="_xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx">
            <AuthnContext>
                <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</AuthnContextClassRef>
            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
    </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Comment: what version of Kentor.AuthServices?

Comment: 0.19.0. As of this writing, the latest version.

Comment: Are you calling `GlobalEnableSha256XmlSignatures`? https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/v0.19.0/Kentor.AuthServices/Configuration/Options.cs#L78 algorithms are registered at the process level so perhaps something else in your site was registering this in the past but no longer is

Comment: Yes, I am. I've stepped through Kentor's code and the System.Security code with nothing definite. I set the framework version to 4.6.1, which doesn't require this explicit initialization, and tried again, both with and without the initialization. 

I'm convinced it's something in my environment, and not something in Kentor Auth Services or System.Security; but, for the first time in a very long time, I'm stumped. I'm going to dig up an old commit and start comparing package.jsons, module versions, and the odd edit to web.config that I might have overlooked. I've done something wrong.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you meant, but it's 4.6.2 that has support for sha256 xml signing built-in.

Comment: Yes, apologies. You're correct.